# Reading values from within an XNode

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have some code that is returning a XNode to me which looks like this:

```
<File>
  <Component>Main</Component>
  <Path>C:\Main\</Path>
  <FileName>main.txt</FileName>
</File>
```

I need to have some C# code that will be able to pull out the value of Path for example (C:\Main). I know that if I was using an XML node I could do it like this:

```
String filePath = xmlNode["Path"].InnerText;
```

Does anybody know what the equivalent would be for an XNode? Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Do you *have* to have it returning an `XNode` rather than an `XElement`? With an `XElement` it's simpler than with an `XNode`:

```
string filePath = fileElement.Element("Path").Value;
```

That will find the *first* `Path` element, and will throw a `NullReferenceException` if there aren't any. An alternative if you're happy to get `null` if there aren't any would be:

```
string filePath = (string) fileElement.Element("Path");
```

If you're really stuck with `XNode`, you'll either have to cast to `XElement` or possibly `XContainer`.

Comment: Im getting exception when trying to cast to XElement. Do you have a solution for that? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ot0: Not without knowing more context, no. I suggest you ask a new question with an example.

Comment: XElement xelm = (XElement) XNodeObject; return exception

Comment: @ot0: That's not a new question with an example. It's a comment with a single statement which isn't enough context to know what's going on.

Comment: I will post a more specific question in few minutes.

Comment: This only works if the XNode is an XElement. It can be a lot of other different things. You can see my answer.

Comment: @JotaBe: Yes, I make that quite clear in my answer - particularly the last line.

Answer (score 12):

You can convert your XNode into XElement to access to its properties, my example:

```
XNode lastNode = myXElement.LastNode;

//if I want to get the 'ID' attribute
string id = (lastNode as XElement).Attribute("ID").Value;
```

Comment: Isn't downcasting bad?

Comment: Ahhh, thanks. I now see XElement will work just fine, though.

Comment: With the example XML as the XNode isn't he more interested in the Elements under the node not the Attributes? so more like string path = (lastNode as XElement).Element("Path").Value;

Answer (score 1):

Casting XNode to XElement works for the individual element to retrieve its value or attributes. But you won't be able to use myXelement.Elements("XXX") to get nested elements. For that you can use xmlNode.Nodes().

This should work:

```
var nodes = xmlNode.Nodes();//Get all nodes under 'File'
var fileNameNode = nodes.Where(el => ((XElement)el).Name.LocalName == "FileName")
.FirstOrDefault();
string filePath = ((XElement)fileNameNode).Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use this:

```
XElement xtr = XElement.Load("path/to/your/xml/file");
String filePath = xtr.Descendants("Path").Single().Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you import System.Xml.XPath you can use XPathSelectElement like this on the XNode object:

```
String component = xmlNode.XPathSelectElement("Component");
String path = xmlNode.XPathSelectElement("Path");
String fileName = xmlNode.XPathSelectElement("FileName");
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what convcrete objets is the abstract `XNode`. From [XNode Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xnode?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> XNode is an abstract common base class for the following types:
>   XComment
>   XContainer: can be XDocument or XElement
>   XDocumentType
>   XProcessingInstruction
>   XText

So you need to check if you can cast it to an `XDocument` or an `XElement`, and use their methods, or use LINQ to XML:

For example:

- [Best way to query XDocument with LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185226/best-way-to-query-xdocument-with-linq)
- [Querying an XDocument vs. Querying an XElement (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/querying-an-xdocument-vs-querying-an-xelement)

Answer (score 0):

```
XNode xnode 
string value = (xnode  as XElement).Value;
```

we can get the value form XElement object so we need to cast XNode to XElement first

should work

Comment: While this may solve the problem, its best to include an explanation as well.

Comment: This is a 7+ year old question, with an accepted answer and this provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.  Code only answers are not considered "good" answers.  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review).