# Best way to query XDocument with LINQ?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an XML document that contains a series of item nodes that look like this:

```
<data>
    <item>
        <label>XYZ</label>
        <description>lorem ipsum</description>
        <parameter type="id">123</parameter>
        <parameter type="name">Adam Savage</parameter>
        <parameter type="zip">90210</parameter>
    </item> 
</data>
```

and I want to LINQ it into an anonymous type like this:

```
var mydata =
    (from root in document.Root.Elements("item")
    select new {
       label = (string)root.Element("label"),
       description = (string)root.Element("description"),
       id = ...,
       name = ...,
       zip = ...
     });
```

What's the best way to pull each parameter type according to the value of its 'type' attribute? Since there are many parameter elements you wind up with `root.Elements("parameter")` which is a collection. The best way I can think to do it is like this by method below but I feel like there must be a better way?

```
(from c in root.Descendants("parameter") where (string)c.Attribute("type") == "id"
select c.Value).SingleOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I would use the built-in query methods in LINQ to XML instead of XPath. Your query looks fine to me, except that:

- If there are multiple items, you'd need to find the descendants of that instead; or just use `Element` if you're looking for direct descendants of the item
- You may want to pull *all* the values at once and convert them into a dictionary
- If you're using different data types for the contents, you might want to cast the element instead of using `.Value`
- You may want to create a method to return the matching `XElement` for a given type, instead of having several queries.

Personally I don't think I'd even use a query expression for this. For example:

```
static XElement FindParameter(XElement element, string type)
{
    return element.Elements("parameter")
                  .SingleOrDefault(p => (string) p.Attribute("type") == type);
}
```

Then:

```
var mydata = from item in document.Root.Elements("item")
             select new {
                 Label = (string) item.Element("label"),
                 Description = (string) item.Element("description"),
                 Id = (int) FindParameter(item, "id"),
                 Name = (string) FindParameter(item, "name"),
                 Zip = (string) FindParameter(item, "zip")
             };
```

I suspect you'll find that's neater than any alternative using XPath, assuming I've understood what you're trying to do.

Comment: yeah that seems like a good approach Jon...the other issue I have to contend with is that sometimes the values are empty strings so having a helper method to handle both the attribute query and gracefully handling the cast to the correct type in the event of empty strings might make the most sense, thanks

Answer (score 8):

use **XPATH**  - it is very fast ( except `xmlreader` - but a **lot** of if's)

```
   using (var stream = new StringReader(xml))
   {
    XDocument xmlFile = XDocument.Load(stream);

    var query = (IEnumerable)xmlFile.XPathEvaluate("/data/item/parameter[@type='id']");

     foreach (var x in query.Cast<XElement>())
     {
         Console.WriteLine(  x.Value );
     }

    }
```

Comment: so is xpath faster than using the built in LINQ methods?

Comment: An unlucky question that was never answered!

Comment: @snappymcsnap seems like the answer is **no**. see this comparison done by [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/comparison-of-xpath-and-linq-to-xml#performance-differences)