# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode to Grid

Tags: json, wpf, gridview

I would like to know what is the easiest way to transform JSON response to GRID view on WPF project.

Answer (score 0):

Since the output of the Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode is an XmlDocument, I can suggest you the next:

```
      XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(this.FilePath);

        var xDocument = XDocument.Load(new XmlNodeReader(doc));

        IEnumerable<Employee> elements
            = xDocument.Descendants(XName.Get("Employee")).Select(element => new Employee
            {
                Id = element.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(xElement => xElement.Name == "EmpId").Value,
                Name = element.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(xElement => xElement.Name == "Name").Value,
                Gender = element.Descendants().FirstOrDefault(xElement => xElement.Name == "Sex").Value,
            });
```

Then you can simple do the next `GridViewName.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection(elements);`

Here is the single Employee node:

```
<Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>   
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Phone Type="Home">423-555-0124</Phone>
    <Phone Type="Work">424-555-0545</Phone>
   <Address>
      <Street>7A Cox Street</Street>
      <City>Acampo</City>
      <State>CA</State>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
      <Country>USA</Country>
    </Address>
 </Employee>
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185226/best-way-to-query-xdocument-with-linq) is some useful example.

Regards.