# Linq to XML get innertext based on attributes

Tags: c#, xml, linq

How can I get the innertext of a xml node based on his attribute (type string)?

My XML-File looks following.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<office:document-content office:version="1.2">
  <office:body>
    <office:text>
      <table:table table:name="Tabelle6" table:style-name="Tabelle6">
        <table:table-row>
          <table:table-cell table:style-name="Tabelle6.A1" office:value-type="string">
            <text:p text:name="Invoice" text:style-name="P6">0001</text:p>
          </table:table-cell>
        </table:table-row>
      </table:table>
    </office:text>
  </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

I want to get the invoice number (0001) from this xml file. 
My code looks like this

```
var xml = XDocument.Load(filePath);

var query = from item in xml.Elements("text:p")
            where (string)item.Attribute("text:name").Value == "Invoice"
            select item.Value;
```

If I execute this, I get an error:

> The ': ' character, hexadecimal value 0x3A, must not be contained in a name.

Maybe it's important, the `content.xml` is a part of a extracted `.odt`-File.

Comment: `text` is not part of the element/attribute name, it's the namespace of that attribute. Try `xml.Elements(XName.Get("text","whatever the namespace url is"))` instead.

Comment: A detailed Explanation can be found [here on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299741(v=vs.110).aspx) (The code above is just an example, not the actual solution)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer thanks. It's the first time I'm working with linq. How can I display the invoice number?

Comment: For that you can [read this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9185226/best-way-to-query-xdocument-with-linq)